# Python interactive shell with smtp..no result..no error

Tags: python, smtp

```
    Python 3.7.0  on win32
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import smtplib
>>> smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

After this second line of code, I am not getting the chevron after hitting enter, neither does it show any error.I have tried the full code in text editor but that too doesn't yield any result. Would be thankful for any help.